# Select month from datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table that has a datetime column  named :**completed_date** (2016-05-27 04:08:53). I would like to select all data for this **current month** while ignoring the time. Something like this:

```
  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, " select  * from eob_posting where
  completed_date=DATE(NOW())");
```

How can i remove the time so that the clause **where** considere only the date ?

Comment: Why are you using `DATE()` if you want the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even shorter than the other answers :-)

Note that a datetime is basically also a string of the form "2016-01-01 12:34:56", so you can just:

```
> SELECT LEFT(NOW(), 7) as YearAndMonth;
YearAndMonth
------------
2016-08
```

So your query is easily expressed as:

```
SELECT * FROM eob_posting
WHERE LEFT(completed_date, 7) = LEFT(NOW(), 7)
```

Happy hunting!

Answer (score 4):

To get the current month, you should use `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`:

```
WHERE YEAR(completed_date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(completed_date) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: His question is confusing about that.

Comment: This will return rows completed just today, not the entire current month.

Comment: @Mureinik OK, I changed it to get the month

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * from eob_posting 
where completed_date >= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)
```